# Range Price Calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a customized version of this code snippet for a jQuery Based Rental Booking Script. Now I've found an issue in this script. I've spent hours to solve the problem, but I am not able to fix it.

The Problem occurs if the last rental day is also the last day of the season. If this happens the day wouldn't be counted and calculated. First I haven't recognized it because if the last day is later than the last day of the season the script works fine.

It would be great if anyone can help me to figure out my problem.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C9kph/)

Here is the code.

```
var MILLI_PER_DAY = 86400000;
/**
 * identifier is a string that identify the season. like 'summer'
 * start and end must be string with date pattern: yyyy/MM/dd
 */
var Season = function(identifier, start, end) {
        this.id = identifier
        this.start = new Date(start);
        this.end = new Date(end);
    }
    /**
     * name is the product name
     * prices is an object that defines the price of each season.
     * e.g. {'summer' : 29.9, 'winter' : 35}
     */
var Product = function(name, prices) {
        this.name = name;
        this.prices = prices;
    }
var seasons = [
new Season('s1', '2012-01-01', '2012-02-28'),
new Season('s2', '2012-03-01', '2012-05-31')];
var products = [
new Product('single-room', {
    's1': 16,
    's2': 12
})];
/**
 * productName is the product name to be bought
 * dateStart and dateEnd is the range that productName will be used and
 * they should be a string representing a date with pattern: yyyy/MM/dd
 */
function calculatePrice(productName, dateStart, dateEnd) {
    var start = new Date(dateStart);
    var end = new Date(dateEnd);
    //finding product
    var product = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        var p = products[i]
        if (p.name == productName) {
            product = p;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (product != null) {
        var totalPrice = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < seasons.length; i++) {
            var s = seasons[i]
            //if this range contains parts or all the season range
            if (start < s.end && end > s.start) {
                var seasonRange = Math.min(s.end, end) - Math.max(s.start, start);
                //due to the start day must count
                var seasonDays = 1 + (seasonRange / MILLI_PER_DAY);
                totalPrice += product.prices[s.id] * seasonDays;
            }
        }
        alert(product.name + " cost " + totalPrice + " in dates from " + dateStart + " to " + dateEnd);
    }
}
calculatePrice('single-room', '2012-02-08', '2012-03-10');
calculatePrice('single-room', '2012-03-05', '2012-05-10');
calculatePrice('single-room', '2012-01-05', '2012-02-10');
```

**EDIT:** 
First at all thanks for your Quick replies:

I have made a new Fiddle where Iam able to show the issue. Sorry for my late reply but I was cooking ;-)

First the facts: 
Season 1 (s1) ist starting at 2012/01/01 and ends at 2012/07/26
Season 2 (s2) ist starting at 2012/07/26 and ends at 2012/12/31

Season 1 costs 1€ a night
Season 1 costs 2€ a night

The first and the last day is counting as one (so the first doesn't count).

Test A: (End date is lower than the seasons end date) 
Summary: Range (and the Price) will be calculated correctly:

See the Fiddle Alert:
range in days: 9 | category: single-room  |  cost 9  |  from: 2012-07-17  |  to: 2012-07-26

Test B: (End date is the same as the seasons end date) 
Summary: The last Date wouldnt count. Range (and the Price) wont be calculated correctly:

See the Fiddle Alert:
range in days: 9 | category: single-room  |  cost 9  |  from: 2012-07-17  |  to: 2012-07-27

Test C: (End date is higher then the seasons end date) 
Summary: The day which equals the last day wouldnt be counted. The 28th would beRange (and the Price) wont be calculated correctly:

See the Fiddle Alert:
range in days: 10  |  category: single-room |  cost 11 |   from: 2012-07-17 |  to: 2012-07-28

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9kph/26/)

---

Dammit, now i have an real issue. It wouldn't work on Sarafi (tried the Mac Version yet) and even the iPhone couln't calulate the price. Firefox and Chrome works well under OSX Lion.

The Price wouln't been calculated it seems that the script stops around these lines:

```
 if ( product != null ) {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    for ( var i=0; i < seasons.length; i++ ) {
      var s = seasons[i]
      //if this range contains parts or all the season range
      if ( start < s.end && end > s.start ) {
        var seasonRange = Math.min(s.end,end) - Math.max(s.start,start);
        //due to the start day must count
        var seasonDays = 1 + (seasonRange/MILLI_PER_DAY);
        totalPrice += product.prices[s.id]*seasonDays;
      }
    }
    alert(product.name + " cost " + totalPrice + " in dates from " + dateStart + " to " + dateEnd);
  }
}
```

I had already checked the safari javascript error log, but i found no issues there.

May you can have a look at it again guys? It would be great ;-)

**UPDATE 26.7.2012**
The problem didn't occur on Safari 6.0 (released today).

Comment: I think I have a small Idea try to add one day more to the end of a season, because is that day the season closes or I am misunderstanding the problem? if you have problems with dates calculations you can try Date.js

Comment: you are right! ;-) i even tried that, but i forgot that there was 1 day added via var seasonDays = 1 +

Sometimes if you stuck at such a point you should wait... drink a beer and try it again later :P

If you are interested in a couch let me know ;-)

Comment: Will do glad to help :-P

Answer (score 0):

I think your string dates are getting cast to dates incorrectly.
all your dates are one day too early.
if you run in your console: new Date('2012-05-25');  you will see the value you are getting.
I changed that to: new Date('2012/05/25'); and it seemed to work correctly.

calculatePrice('single-room','2012/05/25','2012/05/30');

edit: here is my console output:
new Date('2012-03-10')
Fri Mar 09 2012 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
new Date('2012/03/10')
Sat Mar 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

-edit-:
the logic looks wrong.
if you submit: calculatePrice('single-room', '2012-05-31', '2012-05-31'); you get 0 for the price.
this is because start is not less than season end. it's == to season end.  but is still a valid time.
if ( start < s.end && end > s.start ) {
should therefore be:
if ( start <= s.end && end > s.start ) {

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for quick answer. I know the reason why the date is always one day to early. You can find it in this line:

var seasonDays = 1 + (seasonRange / MILLI_PER_DAY);

It's pasted if you need that the first day counts.